# Update deployment from SFDX to Packaging org?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

I have deployed my metadata from SFDX to my Packaging Org, made a package, installed the package on a test org. Now, I've changed some things in my code and I'm ready to update the package.

I've read [this in the SFDX Dev Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_man_pack_create.htm), but it assumes you only need to do this once. [This Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_deploy) walks you through the deployment, but again, just once. I can't find documentation on the iterative process of deploying to packaging org, updating the package, etc.

I tried just redeploying my metadata to the packaging org, but I'm getting errors on my Flows. (The flows dropped their linkage to platform events in the first deployment, so I had to fix them in the packaging org and so now they're later versions.)

Separate from the flows issue, is this the process?

1. update your code in sfdx
2. create a fresh metadata conversion
3. deploy again to your packaging org
4. update version numbers and upload a new package
5. rinse and repeat

And, I've been using 'burner' namespaces on my packaging org because I don't want to make a mistake and screw up my actual namespace. Should I be using the actual namespace with a beta package, updating, updating, then promoting to release package?

Sorry, I know these are basic questions, but it's my first managed package and I can't find docs on the whole process.